# como sacar mensualidades desde una fecha final?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, tablas, consultar

quisiera saber como hacer un query en sql server para poder sacar mensualidades a partir de una fecha final (fecha de vencimiento).
explico un poco como funciona, cada cliente puede sacar a credito de varios productos y cada de estos productos cuentan con una fecha de vencimiento a pagar, lo que necesito es hacer una tabla de amortizacion mensual tomando en cuenta solamente la fecha de vencimiento, asi esta la tabla

```
create table cuota (
id int identity primary key,
cliente varchar(255),
producto varchar(255),
saldo varchar(255),
fechaVencimiento date
);
```

y tengo estos datos de ejemplo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quisiera sacar mas o menos seria asi

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que esa tabla llegue hasta la fecha de vencimiento de forma mensual, que en ese ejemplo es "203002", el saldo y demas no me importa...**aclaro que no tengo acceso para modificar la tabla**

Comment: ¿a partir de qué fecha deben iniciar las _mensualidades_? ¿qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: @jachguate a partir de la fecha siguiente de hoy ...es decir desde marzo hasta su fecha de vencimiento....y solamente he intentado usar where pero sin éxito

Comment: Esas fechas de vencimiento no son fechas.

Comment: @LuisCazares es lo único que tengo...ya que no puedo modificar nada de la tabla ..y manejan así todo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un problema relativamente sencillo de resolver si primero lo divides en partes, encuentras una solución para cada una y luego vas poniendo las soluciones juntas. La famosa estrategia de *divide y vencerás*.

En ese ejercicio, dividiendo en partes, para comenzar te diré que puedes valerte de

- la función `getdate()` para obtener la fecha actual
- la función `DateAdd()` para sumar una cantidad de meses a la fecha actual
- la función `cast()` para convertir de un tipo de dato a otro, por ejemplo de `datetime` a `date`
- la función `convert()` para convertir una fecha a cadena con un formato específico
- la función `substring()` para obtener una parte de una cadena
- algún truco para obtener un listado de números consecutivos que utilizar como *meses* para ir sumando filas, por ejemplo

  ```
    select row_number() from AlgunaTablaConMuchosRegistros
  ```

Vamos entonces por las partes y una solución para cada una:

## Consecutivos

Me valdré de la tabla sys.all_objects, que en una base de datos típica suele tener más de dos o tres mil registros. Dado que hay fechas futuras, para no correr el riesgo, haré un cross join con la misma tabla, con lo cual tendremos ~3K² registros, unos 9 millones, que parecen suficientes meses para cubrir el futuro cercano:

no recomiendo ejecutar la sentencia, puesto que genera millones de registros

```
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) numero 
  from sys.all_objects o1 cross join sys.all_objects o2
```

## Fecha actual

Dado que en la tabla base tienes almacenado un campo con tipo `date`, además de usar la función `getdate()`, que devuelve un `datetime` utilizaré la función `cast` para quedarme solo con la parte `date`:

```
select cast(getdate() as date)
```

Me devuelve la fecha de hoy.

## Suma de meses

Para sumar meses, me valdré de la función `DateAdd()`, pasando como intervalo la palabra `month`.

```
select DateAdd(month, 1, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Me devuelve la fecha de hoy más un mes

```
select DateAdd(month, 12, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Me devuelve la fecha de hoy más doce meses y, finalmente

```
select DateAdd(month, 0, cast(getdate() as date))
```

Me devuelve la misma fecha de hoy.

## Formato de datos

En los datos de ejemplo, muestras que te interesa solamente el año y mes de las fechas, así que, finalmente, aplicaremos la función `convert()`, con el identificador de formato `112` para formatear la fecha como `'yyyymmdd'`

```
select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

Nos devuelve una cadena como `'20230410'`

Y la función `substring()` para tomar los primeros seis caracteres de dicha cadena:

```
select substring(convert(varchar, getdate(), 112), 1, 6)
```

Nos devuelve una cadena como `'202304'`

## CTE's

Preparándonos para ensamblar la solución final, me valdré de estos. CTE es acrónimo de **Common Table Expressions**, y nos sirven, en resumen, para realizar consultas sobre el resultado de otras consultas.

Su sintaxis básica es:

```
with
NombreDelPrimerCTE (
  una sentencia select válida
)
,
NombreDelSegundoCTE (
  otra sentencia select válida
)
select x, y, z
  from UnaTabla
       left join NombreDePrimerCTE on condiciones
       inner join NombreDelSegundoCTE on condiciones
```

Como se ve, puedo utilizar el resultado de las consultas *metidas* en el CTE como si se tratara de *tablas*, o mejor dicho, vistas construidas *al vuelo* en la sentencia misma.

## Solución final

Armando las piezas del rompecabezas, en esta parte final, definiré

- un CTE llamado `cuota` que simula tu tabla subyacente (contiene los mismos datos que das en el ejemplo de la pregunta)
- un CTE llamado `numeros` que contiene una lista de números consecutivos generada con el truco que he explicado antes

Y sobre estos realizaré una consulta que hará un cross join entre los registros del CTE `cuota` y el CTE `numeros`.

En este producto cartesiano realizaré la suma de meses del número menos uno para obtener una fecha de cuota y finalmente utilizaré este cálculo para filtrar y quedarme solo con aquellos *meses* que sean anteriores y hasta la fecha de vencimiento almacenada en `cuota`:

```
with
cuota as (
select 1 id, 'cristhian' cliente, 'Tv' producto, '200' saldo, cast('20300228' as date) fechaVencimiento
union all select 2, 'cristhian', 'pc', '400', '20280131'
union all select 3, 'cristhian', 'cocina', '700', '20250531'
union all select 4, 'cristhian', 'laptop', '800', '20240731'
union all select 5, 'cristhian', 'celular', '900', '20320930'
)
,
numeros as (
select row_number() over (order by (select null)) numero 
  from sys.objects o1 cross join sys.objects o2
)
select   cuota.id
       , cuota.cliente
       , cuota.producto
       , cuota.saldo
       , substring(convert(varchar, cuota.fechaVencimiento, 112), 1, 6) fechaVencimiento
       , numeros.numero numeroCuota
       , substring(convert(varchar, DateAdd(month, numeros.numero - 1, cast(getdate() as date)), 112), 1, 6) FechaCuota
  from cuota
       cross join numeros
 where DateAdd(month, numeros.numero - 1, cast(getdate() as date)) <= cuota.fechaVencimiento
 order by cuota.id, numeros.numero
```

Muestro algunas filas del resultado:

```
id      cliente   producto saldo fechaVencimiento numeroCuota FechaCuota
------- --------- -------- ----- ---------------- ----------- ----------
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           1           202304
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           2           202305
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           3           202306
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           4           202307
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           5           202308
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           6           202309
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           7           202310
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           8           202311
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           9           202312
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           10          202401
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           11          202402
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           12          202403
.....
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           80          202911
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           81          202912
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           82          203001
1       cristhian Tv       200   203002           83          203002
2       cristhian pc       400   202801           1           202304
2       cristhian pc       400   202801           2           202305
....
2       cristhian pc       400   202801           57          202712
2       cristhian pc       400   202801           58          202801
3       cristhian cocina   700   202505           1           202304
3       cristhian cocina   700   202505           2           202305
....
3       cristhian cocina   700   202505           25          202504
3       cristhian cocina   700   202505           26          202505
4       cristhian laptop   800   202407           1           202304
4       cristhian laptop   800   202407           2           202305
....
4       cristhian laptop   800   202407           15          202406
4       cristhian laptop   800   202407           16          202407
5       cristhian celular  900   203209           1           202304
5       cristhian celular  900   203209           2           202305
....
5       cristhian celular  900   203209           113         203208
5       cristhian celular  900   203209           114         203209

(297 rows affected)


Completion time: 2023-04-10T15:18:08.2385703-06:00
```

Comment: Gracias, desconocia el uso de CTE